# Using columns from different tables to create one table

Tags: sql

I am not sure how I can get this code to have three columns for each category (Portrait,Landscape, and Abstract). As of now, it only has one column and all three of these values computed values:

```
SELECT SUM(Price) AS TotalSales_Portrait
FROM Photo
WHERE TransID IS NOT NULL AND PhotoID IN (
SELECT PhotoID
FROM Models) 

UNION

SELECT SUM(Price) AS TotalSales_Landscape
FROM Photo
WHERE TransID IS NOT NULL AND PhotoID IN (
SELECT PhotoID
FROM Landscape)

UNION

SELECT SUM(Price) AS TotalSales_Abstract
FROM Photo
WHERE TransID IS NOT NULL AND PhotoID IN (
SELECT PhotoID
FROM Abstract)
```

[Query output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3qJ6.png)

Any advice is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using pivot as follows

```
select *
from (
SELECT MAX('Portrait') as photo_type,SUM(Price) AS Total_Sales
  FROM Photo
WHERE TransID IS NOT NULL AND PhotoID IN (
SELECT PhotoID
  FROM Models) 
UNION
SELECT MAX('Landscape'),SUM(Price) AS Total_Sales
FROM Photo
WHERE TransID IS NOT NULL AND PhotoID IN (
SELECT PhotoID
FROM Landscape)
)x
pivot (sum(total_sales) for photo_type in(Portrait,Landscape))y
```

Comment: This seems much more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you George, this solved my problem. Here is the final code I have after revising yours:

```
select *
from (
SELECT MAX('Portrait') as photo_type,SUM(Price) AS Total_Sales
  FROM Photo
WHERE TransID IS NOT NULL AND PhotoID IN (
SELECT PhotoID
  FROM Models) 
UNION
SELECT MAX('Landscape'),SUM(Price) AS Total_Sales
FROM Photo
WHERE TransID IS NOT NULL AND PhotoID IN (
SELECT PhotoID
FROM Landscape)
UNION
SELECT MAX('Abstract'),SUM(Price) AS Total_Sales
FROM Photo
WHERE TransID IS NOT NULL AND PhotoID IN (
SELECT PhotoID
FROM Abstract)
)x
pivot (sum(Total_Sales) for photo_type in(Landscape,Abstract,Portrait))y
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `photo type` field in your Photos table it would be easier:

```
SELECT SUM(price), photo_type 
FROM Photos
JOIN Models 
ON Models.PhotoID = Photos.PhotoID
JOIN Landscape
ON Landscape.PhotoID = Photos.PhotoID
JOIN Abstract
ON Abstract.PhotoID = Photos.PhotoID
GROUP BY photo_type
```

If not, you could probably do something like:

```
SELECT SUM(price), type FROM (
  SELECT price, 'Models' as type from Photos 
  WHERE TransID IS NOT NULL AND PhotoID IN (
    SELECT PhotoID
    FROM Models
  )

  UNION

  SELECT price, 'Landscape' as type from Photos 
  WHERE TransID IS NOT NULL AND PhotoID IN (
    SELECT PhotoID
    FROM Landscape
  )

  UNION

  SELECT price, 'Abstract' as type from Abstract
) as photos
GROUP BY type
```

I haven't tested these queries, but they should be at least close to a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would simply use subqueries:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(Price) AS TotalSales_Portrait
        FROM Photo
        WHERE TransID IS NOT NULL AND PhotoID IN (SELECT PhotoID FROM Models) 
       ) as TotalSales_Portrait,
       (SELECT SUM(Price) AS TotalSales_Landscape
        FROM Photo
        WHERE TransID IS NOT NULL AND PhotoID IN (SELECT PhotoID FROM Landscape)
       ) as TotalSales_Landscape,
       (SELECT SUM(Price) AS TotalSales_Abstract
        FROM Photo
        WHERE TransID IS NOT NULL AND PhotoID IN (SELECT PhotoID FROM Abstract)
       ) as TotalSales_Abstract;
```

Alternatively, if the secondary tables have no duplicates:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN m.PhotoId IS NOT NULL THEN price ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN l.PhotoId IS NOT NULL THEN price ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.PhotoId IS NOT NULL THEN price ELSE 0 END)
FROM Photos p LEFT JOIN
     Models m
     ON m.PhotoID = p.PhotoID LEFT JOIN
     Landscape l
     ON l.PhotoID = p.PhotoID LEFT JOIN
     Abstract a
     ON a.PhotoID = p.PhotoID
```